# Why particular JS script (mo.js library) must be placed at the end of the body?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using mo.js library for animations and other effects and noticed that I must place the script tag
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mojs/core"></script>`
at the end of body because if I place it at the head element then I'm getting null reference error "mojs is undefined".
The error occurs in javascript file where I'm using this particular library to create an animation:

```
const polygon = new mojs.Shape({
  parent: '#cell1',
  shape:        'polygon',
  points:       5,
  fill:         { 'deeppink' : '#00F87F' },
  x:            { 'rand(-100%, -200%)' : 0  },
  angle:        { 0: 'rand(0, 360)' },
  radius:       25,

  duration:     2000,
  repeat:       999,
}).play();
```

Could anyone explain why I'm getting this error when script is in head but when it's in body it's working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on whether or not you put in your body, it just matters that you load mojs before using it. Depending on where you use mojs, you can place the script tag in the head.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mojs/core"></script>
  <script>
    console.log(mojs); // mojs is defined
  </script>
</head>
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    console.log(mojs); // is not defined
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mojs/core"></script>
</body>
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mojs/core"></script>
  <script>
    console.log(mojs); // is defined
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you include the library in head or at the bottom of page.

If you are using `mojs` functions before it's loaded on page, you will get the error. if you wait for the library to be available, then using it will be fine.
When you move the library inclusion to the bottom, the DOM gets rende

```js
const polygon = new mojs.Shape({
  parent: '#cell1',
  shape: 'polygon',
  points: 5,
  fill: {
    'deeppink': '#00F87F'
  },
  x: {
    'rand(-100%, -200%)': 0
  },
  angle: {
    0: 'rand(0, 360)'
  },
  radius: 25,

  duration: 2000,
  repeat: 999,
}).play()
```

```css
#cell1 {
  height: 200px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mojs/core"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cell1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's bizzare, I deleted everything else, left exact same code that you posted but it still throws same error. It doesn't even matter because I can leave the script in body but at this point I'm just curious why this happens haha